# How to properly navigate structure of Json file

Tags: c#, json

Noob junior dev here trying to fix some old code written by someone else more senior but left. This person had a json file with a structure like this:

```
A: {
  B: {
    C: stuff1,
    D: stuff2,
    E: stuff3
  }
},
...
```

The old code deserializes the json file into a JObject then tries to get information from the child node like this:

```
stuff1 = jObject["C"];
```

When I run the code, it just fills `stuff1` with `null`. When I use the whole path like this:

```
stuff1 = jObject["A"]["B"]["C"]
```

I get the information I need from the child node. Just wondering if this was an oversight on the original author's part or if there's something I'm not seeing.

Am I right that you shouldn't be able to access the information in the child node without navigating through the tree properly? Is there any more robust way to get the information from the child node directly? I can see a scenario where if the structure of the Json file changes, then the `jObject["A"]["B"]["C"]` will no longer work.

Comment: Maybe the library being used updated? Maybe there's setting that makes the jobject traverses until it finds a matching key?

Comment: Deserialize to a .Net class model and forget about it.

Comment: Oversight or something changed to make his code no longer viable. You're on the right track.

Comment: *Just wondering if this was an oversight on the original author's part or if there's something I'm not seeing.* - we don't have any way of answering that question.  `jObject["A"]["B"]["C"]` is the correct way of directly accessing the `C` property in your JSON.  Or you could use [tag:jsonpath] and do [`jObject.SelectTokens("..C")`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) to select all properties named `C`.

Comment: @dbc I think that might be the best way to robustly get the info I need from a specific child node. Json structure might change in the near future for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Json.NET it looks like a bug or json changed.

However you address the situation write a unit test that shows what json(s) the code is expected to work with. The next dev will be have it easier; and that next dev may be you in 6 months.

## Dealing with changing json

> I can see a scenario where if the structure of the Json file changes, then the jObject["A"]["B"]["C"] will no longer work.

Dealing with changing json is ... let's say hard. If the json libary you're using supports JSONPath you could try with '$..C'. If you're using Json.NET have a look at [Querying JSON with LINQ](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm).

## Fixing the bug

Use `jObject["A"]["B"]["C"]` or deserialise to a class and move on.